# How can I populate a balance field in SQL with grouped Part Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have over 800,000 rows in a table. This is an example of what I have. What I am trying to do is run an update query that populates the Balance column.

| Part No | Current QOH | Supply | Demand | Balance | Previous Part No | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 15 | 0 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| ABC123 | 15 | 5 | 3 |  | ABC123 | 2 |
| ABC123 | 15 | 0 | 5 |  | ABC123 | 3 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 16 |  | ABC123 | 4 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 3 |  | DEF321 | 5 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 30 | 5 |  | DEF321 | 6 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 1 |  | DEF321 | 7 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 14 | 4 |  | DEF321 | 8 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 9 |  | DEF321 | 9 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 4 |  | DEF321 | 10 |

There are many Part Nos, They are all grouped, as shown.

For the first Part No in a group, I want to start with Current QOH, subtract the Demand and add the Supply. Then for all the remaining Part Nos in the group, I don't start with Current QOH, instead I start with the previous row Balance. Then from there I subtract the Demand and add the Supply. Once we get to the next group of Part Nos, I start with Current QOH again. I have the Previous Part No which I populated using Lag. That's helpful in determining if the Part No is the first in a group or not.

After populating Balance, it should look like this:

| Part No | Current QOH | Supply | Demand | Balance | Previous Part No | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 14 |  | 1 |
| ABC123 | 15 | 5 | 3 | 16 | ABC123 | 2 |
| ABC123 | 15 | 0 | 5 | 11 | ABC123 | 3 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 16 | 6 | ABC123 | 4 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 3 | 3 | DEF321 | 5 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 30 | 5 | 28 | DEF321 | 6 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 1 | 27 | DEF321 | 7 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 14 | 4 | 37 | DEF321 | 8 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 9 | 28 | DEF321 | 9 |
| DEF321 | 22 | 0 | 4 | 24 | DEF321 | 10 |

Currently, I load the data into Excel, manually populate the first Balance field, then apply a formula, which I copy down. Then I load the data back into SQL.

I also tried a VB script that looks at each row, one at a time and makes the calculations and populates Balance. But with 800K records, that script takes hours to run.

I am looking for an SQL solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, in SQL tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window functions` to calculate your running balance like so:

```
select partNo, CurrentQOH, supply, Demand, 
    First_Value(CurrentQOH) over(partition by partno order by id) 
    + Sum(supply-demand) over(partition by partno order by id) Balance,
    PreviousPartNo, Id
from t
```

Comment: Works perfectly